# Is the Firebase Firestore read request count correct?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

If I request a read operation in Firestore like the following and retrieve only one document, does the read count increase by one?

```
Query query = todosRef.doc(user.uid).collection('calendars');
query = query.where('isDone', isEqualTo: true);
query = query.orderBy('timestamp', descending: false);
await query.limit(1).get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you add a call to `.limit(1)`, to limit the results of the query to one document, then you'll have to pay only for a single read. However, there is something that you should take into consideration. If your query somehow yields no result, according to the official documentation regarding [Firestore pricing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations), it said:

> **Minimum charge for queries**
>
> There is a minimum charge of **one document read** for each query that you perform, even if the query returns no results.

So if, for example, you try to query 1.000 calendars and you get no results, you're still charged with one read.